# Use swift to add a tableView to the custom view

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I used Swift to write a project (written before using this project in the project). I encountered a problem in the process:

A custom view has a button, click on the button will pop up a list, click on one of the list of cells, the contents of the button will become the contents of the cell. It is known that the code is written in Objective C

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UITableView *tableView;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *cityBtn;

- (UITableView *)tableView {

    if (_tableView == nil) {
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    tableView.dataSource  = self;
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    tableView.alpha = 0.9;
    tableView.x = self.cityBtn.x;
    tableView.y = CGRectGetMaxY(self.cityBtn.frame);
    tableView.width = self.cityBtn.width;
    tableView.heigth = 0;
    tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    [self addSubview:tableView];
    _tableView = tableView;

}

return _tableView;

}
```

Will this code how to convert into Swift

Answer (score 0):

```
var tableView = UITableView();//or TableView
tableView.dataSource  = self;
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black;
tableView.alpha = 0.9;
tableView.x = self.cityBtn.x;
tableView.y = CGRectGetMaxY(self.cityBtn.frame);
tableView.width = self.cityBtn.width;
tableView.heigth = 0;
tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
self.addSubview(tableView);
_tableView = tableView;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issues long ago. There is some good reference that I've listed below for help.

- Swift to ObjC: https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/converter/
- http://codevoyagers.com/2016/03/23/how-we-migrated-our-objective-c-projects-to-swift-step-by-step/

Otherthen that your convered code.

> ```
> if tableView == nil {
>     var tableView = UITableView()
>     tableView.dataSource = self
>     tableView.delegate = self
>     tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
>     tableView.alpha = 0.9
>     tableView.x = cityBtn.x
>     tableView.y = cityBtn.frame.maxY
>     tableView.width = cityBtn.width
>     tableView.heigth = 0
>     tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
>     addSubview(tableView)
>     tableView = tableView
> }
> return tableView
> ```

Thank you.

Comment: I originally wrote this, but did not show it after execution

Comment: Hi, I've implimented the code : beetxt.com/2F3 . Please raise query if anything is wrong. Thank you.